# I am trying to automate the Clear trip website getting selenium.WebDriverException while selecting To city through selenium and java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, selenium3

```
package calendar_autosuggestivedropdown;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Cleartrip {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.cleartrip.com/");
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
        driver.findElement(By.id("FromTag")).sendKeys("mum");
        // Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul[@class='autoComplete']/li")));
        driver.findElement(By.id("FromTag")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        String script = "return document.getElementById(\"FromTag\").value;";
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        String scripttext = (String) js.executeScript(script);
        System.out.println(scripttext);  // Mumbai 

        // To City 

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='ToTag']")).sendKeys("Pari");
        String scriptTo = "return document.getElementById(\"ToTag\").value;";
        WebDriverWait waitTo = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        waitTo.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ui-id-2']")));

        while (!scriptTo.equalsIgnoreCase("Paris, FR - Le Bourget (LBG)")) {

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='ToTag']")).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
            scriptTo = (String)js.executeScript(scriptTo);
            System.out.println(scriptTo); 
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: What is the exact line where the exception occurs?

Comment: Line 56 : `scriptTo = (String)js.executeScript(scriptTo);`
Exception : **Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Pari is not defined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you are trying to select a particular matching option from that auto suggested drop down.

You can able to select `Mumbai` from the first drop down because there is only one match is coming but you are not able to select the second because there are multiple matches.

To select a desired matching option, I recommend you to use `driver.findElements()` instead of JavaScriptExecutor and need to modify locators in your code to make it work properly.

Below is the modified code which selects `Paris, FR - Le Bourget (LBG)` option from `to` auto suggestion drop down :

```
package calendar_autosuggestivedropdown;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Cleartrip {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.cleartrip.com/");

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);

        // From
        WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.id("FromTag"));
        from.sendKeys("mum");
        // Locating options from 'from' dropdown
        String fromOptiosXapth = "//ul[@id='ui-id-1']/li";
        // Waiting until the from drop down options get displayed
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(fromOptiosXapth)));
        // Selecting the first option
        from.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        // Fetching the value
        String fromPlace = from.getAttribute("value");
        System.out.println("=> From : "+fromPlace);

        // To
        WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.id("ToTag"));
        to.sendKeys("Pari");
        // Locating options from 'from' drop down
        String toOptionsXPath = "//ul[@id='ui-id-2']/li";
        // Waiting until the to drop down options get displayed
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(toOptionsXPath)));
        // Option that you want to select
        String optionThatYouWantToSelect = "Paris, FR - Le Bourget (LBG)";
        // Fetching all the to drop down options and storing in the list
        List<WebElement> toOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath(toOptionsXPath));
        // Looping and selecting if it matches with our required option
        for(WebElement toOption: toOptions) {
            if(toOption.getText().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(optionThatYouWantToSelect)) {
                toOption.click();
                break;
            }
        }
        // Fetching the selected option from to drop down
        String toPlace = to.getAttribute("value");
        System.out.println("=> To   : "+toPlace);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Hi @Palak Soni, check my answer and let me know it is working for you or not? Still if you want to use JavaScriptExecutor then I will post an answer according to that as well... Thank you

Comment: While running the program most of the time throwing TimeOut Exception what is the cause of it even i put wait for 10 Seconds.

Comment: At what line are you getting this exception? I think, sometimes auto suggestion drop down taking time to load the list so you are getting that exception. Try to increase the wait time to 1 minute, it may solve the problem...